How to set linux param acpi_osi with string parameter?
i cant add "Windows 2015" string onto acpi_osi ...
i ran command: sudo dmesg |grep -i added
and
it do not show up added(Windows 2015)
if a set acpi_osi='2015 Windows'
former command show up added(2015 Windows)
What is the right way?

The handler for acpi_osi= will report failure when it tries to add a duplicate entry.
It seems that the string "Windows 2015" was already added to the default Linux _OSI() response list in 2015, starting with kernel version 4.1, so the boot log doesn't show "added" because it cannot add the same string a second time. (The current list for the latest kernel looks like this.)

Thx for response and reference... What about dmi honored message?
